# Properly initialize a vector before passing to unsafe code

Tags: vector, rust, unsafe

Given a piece of unsafe code (bindings to a system library) of type:

```
pub fn unsafe_system_call(buf: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_short) {}
```

I am wrapping it with a function:

```
pub fn wrapper(buf: &mut [u8]) {
    unsafe {
        ffi::unsafe_system_call(buf.as_ptr() as *mut _);
    }
}
```

Calling `wrapper()` with a static array buffer is possible:

```
let mut buf: [u8; 7] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
wrapper(&mut buf);
```

But when the size of the buffer should be dynamic, and attempting to use a `Vec`, it's unclear how to init the buffer:

```
let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(runtime_size);
wrapper(&mut buf);
```

This code just creates a `Vec` but doesn't initialize the memory in preparation of an unsafe call, and the library call doesn't execute correctly.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: This isn't what you asked about, but:  `wrapper()` must check that the length of the slice is long enough, or it's unsound.

Comment: Does `unsafe_system_call()` writes into `buf`? If yes, this is UB.

Comment: @KevinReid - very good point, this is already handled in the actual code, I removed that part for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a zero-initialized vector using the `vec!` macro:

```
let mut buf = vec![0u8; runtime_size];
```

You can also map a fixed range (in case you need initialization based on index `i`) and collect it as a more general method:

```
let mut buf: Vec<u8> = (0..runtime_size).map(|_i| 0u8).collect();
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed this :)